# JSTL tag library date formate

Tags: date, tags, jstl, date-format

I am trying to parse a date like 2014-05-09T13:44:07.658Z
I am using jstl fmt tag as below

```
<fmt:parseDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" value="${createdTime}" var="changeToDateFormat" />
                                <fmt:formatDate value="${changeToDateFormat}" pattern="dd" var="Day" /> 
                            <fmt:formatDate value="${changeToDateFormat}" pattern="MM" var="Mon" />         
                            <fmt:formatDate value="${changeToDateFormat}" pattern="yyyy" var="Yr" />
                            <div class="cellContent noBorder" style="height: 99px;"><c:out value="${Mon}"/>/<c:out value="${Day}"/>/<c:out value="${Yr}"/></div>
```

I am getting dateformat exception..
Can anybody help me ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: And what is the exception? Any stacktrace?

Comment: this is fixed. I was looking wrong direction. It is caused by parent Object of createdTime property..Thanks for your reply.